# How can I efficiently rearrange characters of strings in a list? (python)

Tags: python, string, replace

I'm trying to take a list of equal length strings and make a new list where each string in the new list is composed of the indexed(?) letters of each of the strings of the previous list. I.e.

```
['ABCDEF','AJSDNG','WIQUDK']
```

would become

```
['AAW','BJI','CSQ','DDU','END','FGK']
```

Is there an efficient/simple way I can do this? I don't really care if the output is a list of strings tuples as long as it's ordered. I want to solve the problem without using external libraries. I know I can turn the first string into three individual lists and then recombine them with `zip` or something but I feel their might be less convoluted ways to solve the problem. I'm new to python so their might be a function that I just don't know how to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct to use zip here. Here is a shorthand:

```
words = ['ABCDEF','AJSDNG','WIQUDK']
print(["".join(word) for word in zip(*words)])
```

Here, zip will take the strings themselves as iterables and generate tuples with the consecutive letters which will then be joined.